# TeamCity Can not find reference to local path in ant script

Tags: ant, teamcity, javac

I am new to TeamCity as you will be able to tell.
I have a build file which runs locally fine but on Team City I get a Compilation error: javac.

```
[javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\lib does not exist.
[10:23:30][compile] C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\lib does not exist.
```

The ant script:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
<fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
</fileset>
<fileset dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

How can I get TeamCity to recognise this path? I have tried adding this a parameter but with no luck.

Comment: Your Ant script is missing. It looks like you are locally running Ant from RAD. My guess is that TeamCity can't access these WebSphere libraries given they are not on the server.

Comment: You are exactly right @Roberg How can I put this on the server?

Comment: You could install Rational Build Utility. Which is basically a 'headless' RAD that will just run the Ant scripts, and let TeamCity trigger that. Or you create your own Ant scripts independent from RAD and just copy over the jars you need, then let `javac` use that classpath.